# Multiple entries for same dependencies shown in WhatDoIHave method

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, structuremap

Is it normal to see multiple entries for the same dependency when running ObjectFactory.WhatDoIHave() with StructureMap?  For example, I am seeing:

```
ISomeClass (Some.Namespace.ISomeClass)                8cddad2d-565b-4a6f-b487-f4ec0225335d     Configured Instance of Another.Namespace.SomeClass, Some.Assembly, Version=4.5.0.15805, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null                                              
Scoped as:  Transient
                                                      5e015488-4f81-48c2-a6c2-4b94a66de76c     Configured Instance of Another.Namespace.SomeClass, Some.Assembly, Version=4.5.0.15805, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null                                              
                                                      5fb1a6d9-395a-42db-a226-5563d35ac8aa     Configured Instance of Another.Namespace.SomeClass, Some.Assembly, Version=4.5.0.15805, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null                                              
                                                      d431713f-dbdb-41c4-993f-d696433d805f     Configured Instance of Another.Namespace.SomeClass, Some.Assembly, Version=4.5.0.15805, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null                                              
                                                      1a14e0cf-52f2-4f7a-ac71-937fa5faade9     Configured Instance of Another.Namespace.SomeClass, Some.Assembly, Version=4.5.0.15805, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null                                              
                                                      c6f638e7-824d-42e2-9a90-765921ae1da9     Configured Instance of Another.Namespace.SomeClass, Some.Assembly, Version=4.5.0.15805, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null                                              
                                                      7627f1d5-23a7-4220-a400-d8a3509028f0     Configured Instance of Another.Namespace.SomeClass, Some.Assembly, Version=4.5.0.15805, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null                                              
                                                      c693eae9-00a3-46e8-a6b1-923a82a5d87c     Configured Instance of Another.Namespace.SomeClass, Some.Assembly, Version=4.5.0.15805, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
```

Is it normal to see this?  As I use the system, the number of entries continue to grow.

Note:  Keep in mind, I only ever have a 1-to-1 relationship between interface and concrete class.  I never have multiple implementations of the same interface.

Comment: That doesn't look normal. Do you run the configuration many times or have something in your code that injects something into the container. Normally you just configure your container once when the application starts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is normal for **transient** dependencies.

Transient means that a new instance is created every time that you request a service.